# Does IE & Firefox have a div width limit?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

In short, I'm trying to make a weather scroller that will display the weather horizontally for about 50 cities. The issue I'm having is that both IE and FF are making 2-3 lines worth of cities while Chrome keeps it in a nice horizontal line. So Chrome has 1 line scrolling with the weather and IE+FF  have 2-3. I've pasted my current code at pastebin to not overflow the page.

http://pastebin.ca/1316234

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Edit: Ignore the last Javascript line that reads `widnow.onresize`.

Answer (score 2):

You do the following:

```
.weather_entry{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
}
```

This is not allowed. Float is only supported on block level elements. Using the following should do what you want.

```
.weather_entry{
 display:block
 float:left;
}
```

The float will make sure that the elements apear inline.
Also i'm not quite sure why you make the marquee float:left but you might have your reasons for that.

Comment: Actually,it is allowed. According to CSS2.1 C.3.17 Section 9.7, browser is supposed to change display:inline to display:block in this case. So, a float with display:inline specified behaves differently from a float with display:inline-table specified.

Comment: The “display: inline; float: left;” is usually used to “fix” IE’s double margin bug for floated elements. And the float forces the element to block anyway, so that doesn’t really change much.